# Disable Dimmable Close Event in Semanticui

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I created a Dimmer using SemanticUI and I am trying to disable closing the dimmer when clicking on dimmer area.

I can see that there is an option to do so (closable behavior). But How do I do it only to this JSFiddle without changing the JS of SemanticUI.?
I tried this which I assumed it should work, but cannot find why not.

```
 $('body')
   .dimmer('closable',false)
   .dimmer('show');
```

});

[Dimmer SemanticUI](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer.html#/settings)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3m0v03w/18/)

Comment: How do I pass the parameters? I think it requires only small change but cannot seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

For some reason chaining the commands doesn't have the desired effect.

Running `$('body').dimmer({closable: false});` before `$('body').dimmer('show');` does disable the closable behavior.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uooxmtbr/

edit: it seems the chaining does work, you just need to pass the 'closable' option as an object rather than a string.